# Parse XML to create table definition

Tags: xml, oracle, parsing

I've an XML document with a few nodes as shown below. Now, I need to create table columns dynamically based on the nodes received in the XML.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<person>
   <row>
       <name>Tony</name>
       <Address>
           <State>Kerala</State>
           <City>Calicut</City>
       </Address>
   </row>
   <row>
       <name>Jim</name>
       <Address>
           <State>AP</State>
           <City>Vizag</City>
           <Country>India</Country>
       </Address>
   </row>
  <row>
       <name>Anto</name>
       <Address>
           <State>Maharashtra</State>
           <City>Mumbai</City>
           <Country>India</Country>
           <PinCode>20000</PinCode>
       </Address>
   </row>
</person>
```

After parsing the first row from the xml, my table should look like below

```
Person
name     State    City
Tony     Kerala   Calicut
```

After parsing second row from the xml, my table looks like

```
Person
name     State    City      Country
Tony     Kerala   Calicut
Jim      AP       Vizag     India
```

After parsing third row from the xml, my table looks like

```
Person
name     State        City      Country  PinCode
Tony     Kerala       Calicut
Jim      AP           Vizag     India
Anto     Maharashtra  Mumbai    India    20000
```

Can someone help to find out the solution for this?

To be more clear, suppose if my xml is as below

```
 <Result>
   <M395B2C2>222</M395B2C2> 
  <M395B2C3>333</M395B2C3> 
  <M395B2C4>444</M395B2C4> 
  <M395B2C5>555</M395B2C5> 
  <M395B2C6>6666</M395B2C6> 
  <M395B2C7>77</M395B2C7> 
  <M395B2C8>88</M395B2C8> 
  <M395B2C9>99</M395B2C9> 
  </Result>
```

I need to create a temporary table with M395B2C2 to M395B2C9 coulmns as it corresponding values. Again if I get new xml as below

```
<Result>
  <M395B2C10>110</M395B2C10> 
  <M395B2C11>11</M395B2C11> 
  <M395B2C12>122</M395B2C12> 
  <M395B2C13>123</M395B2C13> 
  <M395B2C14>145</M395B2C14> 
  <M395B2C15>167</M395B2C15> 
</Result>
```

to the same temporary table I need to add the remaining columns(M395B2C10 to M395B2C15) and its values

Comment: Shouldn't you create your table once with all the columns you expect to ever receive in the XML? How would you determine the column sizes - you'd have to add and modify columns as well as creating the table. Why do you want to do this dynamically?

Comment: this xml comes from different system and I dont have the defined count. So the table cloumns will be dynamically created by reading the xml

Comment: I still don't get it. You have to store data extracted from an XML file in your database, but you don't know what data, or what columns; so how will it be queried and used? Is this is one-off process, or will you have to create new tables each time you get a file, or modify existing tables? That level on instability in your schema doesn't seem sensible or useful.  Maybe you should just store the raw XML instead?

Comment: Just store the complete XML and create a view with XML queries.

Comment: @Alex, yes i'll have to create a new temporary table each time and process the data and then delete it before returning the procedure. So can you please give some sample, how to read dynamical columns

Comment: Just store the complete XML and create a view with XML queries -- Can you please help me on this??

Comment: If the data is that transitory, why have it in a table at all? Maybe you meant a PL/SQL collection? From your update it seems like you're really getting data value pairs you want to do something with; if you were storing them then they'd be two columns with multiple rows, not a single row with one column per node name. Maybe explaining what processing you're doing would make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the node names and values in a procedure and then do something with them, you can use an Xquery to do that; this uses a cursor to loop over them:

```
create or replace procedure process_xml(p_xml xmltype) is
begin
  for rec in (
    select node_name, node_value,
      max(length(node_value)) over (partition by node_name) as max_value_len
    from xmltable('for $i in //Result//* return $i' passing p_xml
      columns node_name varchar2(30) path 'name(.)',
        node_value varchar2(200) path '.'
    )
  )
  loop
    -- process data
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.node_name || ' -> ' || rec.node_value);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

When called with the first of your 'results' documents you get:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
begin
  process_xml(xmltype(
'<Result>
  <M395B2C2>222</M395B2C2> 
  <M395B2C3>333</M395B2C3> 
  <M395B2C4>444</M395B2C4> 
  <M395B2C5>555</M395B2C5> 
  <M395B2C6>6666</M395B2C6> 
  <M395B2C7>77</M395B2C7> 
  <M395B2C8>88</M395B2C8> 
  <M395B2C9>99</M395B2C9> 
</Result>'));
end;
/

anonymous block completed
M395B2C2 -> 222
M395B2C3 -> 333
M395B2C4 -> 444
M395B2C5 -> 555
M395B2C6 -> 6666
M395B2C7 -> 77
M395B2C8 -> 88
M395B2C9 -> 99
```

If you need to preserve the value between calls, but within one session, you could maintain a collection type that holds the pairs, using a package to maintain the state.

Or you could [create a global temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54447) with the node name/value pairs as columns, so each new node from your document becomes a row in the table, not a new column:

```
create global temporary table gtt_xml_nodes (node_name varchar2(30),
  node_value number);
```

Note that this is created once at schema level, not created or modified each time you run the procedure.

Then your procedure can insert rows into the global table:

```
create or replace procedure process_xml(p_xml xmltype) is
begin
  insert into gtt_xml_nodes (node_name, node_value)
  select node_name, to_number(node_value)
  from xmltable('for $i in //Result//* return $i' passing p_xml
    columns node_name varchar2(30) path 'name(.)',
      node_value varchar2(200) path '.'
  );
end;
/
```

You can call it twice with different documents:

```
begin
  process_xml(xmltype(
'<Result>
  <M395B2C2>222</M395B2C2> 
  <M395B2C3>333</M395B2C3> 
  <M395B2C4>444</M395B2C4> 
  <M395B2C5>555</M395B2C5> 
  <M395B2C6>6666</M395B2C6> 
  <M395B2C7>77</M395B2C7> 
  <M395B2C8>88</M395B2C8> 
  <M395B2C9>99</M395B2C9> 
</Result>'));

  process_xml(xmltype(
'<Result>
  <M395B2C10>110</M395B2C10> 
  <M395B2C11>11</M395B2C11> 
  <M395B2C12>122</M395B2C12> 
  <M395B2C13>123</M395B2C13> 
  <M395B2C14>145</M395B2C14> 
  <M395B2C15>167</M395B2C15> 
</Result>'));

end;
/
```

And afterwards the GTT contains the node pairs from both calls:

```
select count(*) from gtt_xml_nodes;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ae086/1).

But it's rare to really need to define a GTT, and it's very likely you can (and should) do this with a PL/SQL collection, or directly in a cursor loop - it depends what processing you're doing...